# Labels for Every Nth Date in Pgfplots

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, dateplot

I want to create a graph with dates on the *x*-axis. I started with the `dateplot` library in `pgfplots`. I want date labels only for every *third* date, e.g., March 4, March 7, March 10, etc., but I can't quite figure out how to do it. I looked at similar questions on here, but I'm still confused, and I would really appreciate some help. My code follows:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{width=6in,compat=newest}
\usepgfplotslibrary{dateplot}

\begin{document}

    \begin{flushleft}

        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \begin{axis}[
                date coordinates in=x,
                xtick=data,
                xticklabel={\month/\day},
                xtick distance=7,
            ]
                \addplot[color=black,mark=*] coordinates {
                    (2020-03-04,7)
                    (2020-03-05,11)
                    (2020-03-06,13)
                    (2020-03-07,14)
                    (2020-03-08,14)
                    (2020-03-09,16)
                    (2020-03-10,17)
                    (2020-03-11,27)
                    (2020-03-12,32)
                    (2020-03-13,40)
                    (2020-03-14,53)
                    (2020-03-15,69)
                    (2020-03-16,94)
                    (2020-03-17,144)
                    (2020-03-18,190)
                    (2020-03-19,231)
                    (2020-03-20,292)
                    (2020-03-21,351)
                    (2020-03-22,409)
                    (2020-03-23,536)
                    (2020-03-24,662)
                    (2020-03-25,799)
                    (2020-03-26,1216)
                    (2020-03-27,1465)
                    (2020-03-28,1804)
                    (2020-03-29,2136)
                    (2020-03-30,2474)
                    (2020-03-31,3011)
                    (2020-04-01,3518)
                    (2020-04-02,4045)
                    (2020-04-03,4566)
                    (2020-04-04,5277)
                    (2020-04-05,5940)
                    (2020-04-06,6360)
                    (2020-04-07,6910)
                    (2020-04-08,7530)
            };
            \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}

    \end{flushleft}

\end{document}
```

The code produces this graph:[image]

But I want something with an *x*-axis like the one on this graph that I made in Excel:[image].

Comment: Context: [Number of Coronavirus Cases in L.A. County](https://www.latimes.com/projects/california-coronavirus-cases-tracking-outbreak/).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can test whether `\ticknum` is divisible by 7, and only print the tick if that is the case.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{width=6in,compat=newest}
\usepgfplotslibrary{dateplot}

\begin{document}

    \begin{flushleft}

        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \begin{axis}[
                date coordinates in=x,
                xtick=data,
                xticklabel={\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\itest}{%
                (int(\ticknum/7)==\ticknum/7 ? 1 :0)}%
                \ifnum\itest=1\relax
                \pgfcalendarmonthshortname{\month}/\day
                \fi},
                xtick distance=7,
            ]
                \addplot[color=black,mark=*] coordinates {
                    (2020-03-04,7)
                    (2020-03-05,11)
                    (2020-03-06,13)
                    (2020-03-07,14)
                    (2020-03-08,14)
                    (2020-03-09,16)
                    (2020-03-10,17)
                    (2020-03-11,27)
                    (2020-03-12,32)
                    (2020-03-13,40)
                    (2020-03-14,53)
                    (2020-03-15,69)
                    (2020-03-16,94)
                    (2020-03-17,144)
                    (2020-03-18,190)
                    (2020-03-19,231)
                    (2020-03-20,292)
                    (2020-03-21,351)
                    (2020-03-22,409)
                    (2020-03-23,536)
                    (2020-03-24,662)
                    (2020-03-25,799)
                    (2020-03-26,1216)
                    (2020-03-27,1465)
                    (2020-03-28,1804)
                    (2020-03-29,2136)
                    (2020-03-30,2474)
                    (2020-03-31,3011)
                    (2020-04-01,3518)
                    (2020-04-02,4045)
                    (2020-04-03,4566)
                    (2020-04-04,5277)
                    (2020-04-05,5940)
                    (2020-04-06,6360)
                    (2020-04-07,6910)
                    (2020-04-08,7530)
            };
            \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}

    \end{flushleft}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! This works perfectly. Do you know if there's a way to display the month with a three-letter abbreviation, e.g., 03/04 as Mar 04? Should I ask this as a separate question?

Comment: @bclzyjhr Sure, with `\pgfcalendarmonthshortname{\month}`. I added this to the code. You can also use `\pgfcalendarmonthshortname{\month}~\day` if you do not like the slash.

Comment: Thank you so much! It works like a charm.

Answer (score 4):

Remove `xtick=data` from your code, and add in some minor ticks if you want ticks on each day. Thanks to Schrödinger's cat for the abbreviated month names.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{width=6in,compat=newest}
\usepgfplotslibrary{dateplot}

\begin{document}

    \begin{flushleft}

        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \begin{axis}[
                date coordinates in=x,
                xticklabel={\pgfcalendarmonthshortname{\month}/\day},
                xtick distance=3,
                minor x tick num=2,
               x tick label style={rotate=90}
            ]
                \addplot[color=black,mark=*] coordinates {
                    (2020-03-04,7)
                    (2020-03-05,11)
                    (2020-03-06,13)
                    (2020-03-07,14)
                    (2020-03-08,14)
                    (2020-03-09,16)
                    (2020-03-10,17)
                    (2020-03-11,27)
                    (2020-03-12,32)
                    (2020-03-13,40)
                    (2020-03-14,53)
                    (2020-03-15,69)
                    (2020-03-16,94)
                    (2020-03-17,144)
                    (2020-03-18,190)
                    (2020-03-19,231)
                    (2020-03-20,292)
                    (2020-03-21,351)
                    (2020-03-22,409)
                    (2020-03-23,536)
                    (2020-03-24,662)
                    (2020-03-25,799)
                    (2020-03-26,1216)
                    (2020-03-27,1465)
                    (2020-03-28,1804)
                    (2020-03-29,2136)
                    (2020-03-30,2474)
                    (2020-03-31,3011)
                    (2020-04-01,3518)
                    (2020-04-02,4045)
                    (2020-04-03,4566)
                    (2020-04-04,5277)
                    (2020-04-05,5940)
                    (2020-04-06,6360)
                    (2020-04-07,6910)
                    (2020-04-08,7530)
            };
            \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}

    \end{flushleft}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you! I had not used that earlier because I wanted to have tick marks at every date, but I think your method with minor ticks in between looks best.

Comment: @bclzyjhr I did not realize when I posted that you wanted ticks on each day. I've edited.